# Python numpy ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,2,3) into shape (2,2)

Tags: python, numpy

I want to zip two arrays that have the same lengths but contain different dimensions of matrices.

```
a1 = np.ones((2,2,3),dtype=np.uint8)
a2 = np.ones((2,2,3),dtype=np.uint8)*2
b1 = np.ones((2,2),dtype=np.uint8)
b2 = np.ones((2,2),dtype=np.uint8)*2
```

Now Two arrays are c1, c2.

```
c1 = [a1,a2]
c2 = [b1,b2]
```

when I try to zip them like this.

```
res = np.array(list(zip(c1,c2)))
```

I get an error like following.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 1, in 
> ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2,2,3) into shape (2,2)

Why I am getting this error?
How Can I fix it?

Comment: You are getting this error because `a2` is `3D array` and `a1,b1,a2` are `2D array` so shape of array `a2` is different

Comment: @AnuragDabas How can I fix it? I actually want to randomize the array afterward.

Comment: Could you give us your expected output? `res =` ?

Comment: @RikardOlsson for this my expected output would be [(a1,b1),(a2,b2)].

Comment: As Anurag says, you cannot create an array of arrays that have different shapes (try your self to describe the shape of `res`). If you try and explain in more detail what your expected output is and what you want to do with it, it will be easier to help you

Answer (score 1):

`c1` and `c2` are **lists**, not arrays.  Combining them produces a 2 element list of tuples:

```
In [84]: C = list(zip(c1,c2))
In [85]: C
Out[85]: 
[(array([[[1, 1, 1],
          [1, 1, 1]],
  
         [[1, 1, 1],
          [1, 1, 1]]], dtype=uint8),
  array([[1, 1],
         [1, 1]], dtype=uint8)),
 (array([[[2, 2, 2],
          [2, 2, 2]],
  
         [[2, 2, 2],
          [2, 2, 2]]], dtype=uint8),
  array([[2, 2],
         [2, 2]], dtype=uint8))]
```

This is a mix of (2,2,3) and (2,2) shaped arrays.  Sometimes when trying to make an array from mixed shape arrays, we get a `ragged array` warning (as of numpy v1.19) and an object dtype array.  But with this combination of shapes, the result is an error.

A way around that error is to create an object dtype array with the desire shape, and fill it from the list:

```
In [93]: arr = np.empty((2,2), object)
In [94]: arr[:]=C
In [95]: arr
Out[95]: 
array([[array([[[1, 1, 1],
                [1, 1, 1]],

               [[1, 1, 1],
                [1, 1, 1]]], dtype=uint8), array([[1, 1],
                                                  [1, 1]], dtype=uint8)],
       [array([[[2, 2, 2],
                [2, 2, 2]],

               [[2, 2, 2],
                [2, 2, 2]]], dtype=uint8), array([[2, 2],
                                                  [2, 2]], dtype=uint8)]],
      dtype=object)
```

Apart from the print display, the array has, few if any, advantages over the `C` list.